# Aws Mobile Hub development

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using Aws Mobile Hub to build an ios application which provides facebook login button and fetch the data from that login and Store it in user profile in Cloud. I added these features using Aws mobile hub and downloaded a Sample App.When I sign in, how can I store/view this information in Aws?

Comment: What do you want to store about the user? i.e. email address? -------- How are you attempting to store the information? i.e database? flat files?

Comment: Username, Key . Trying to store information in a database

Answer (score 2):

As Usman mentioned, the NoSQL Database Feature can be used to create a user database. When a user signs in with Facebook in your app, they are given a Cognito identity id in the cognito identity pool that is associated with your app. You can see the Cognito identity IDs for your app in the AWS Cognito console under your app's Identity Pool. If you would like to correlate your Facebook user's information with their Cognito identity ID, one solution is to create a private NoSQL table within Mobile Hub with fields for whatever profile information that you would like and populate it upon user sign-in within the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sample application for your project. It contains all the necessary information about the database and its connectivity.
They have also provided the sample project for noSqldatabase learning. So try that it  will be helpful.